# Incorrect Year in the Chronological Grouping in the Profile Page

Tags: bug, android-app

A post I made in January 2014 appears under "earlier this month" in the profile page.

**Clarifications:**

- The post is a question.

Comment: Which kind of post?  Question?  Answer?  Comment?

Comment: The post is a question.

Comment: Well how 'bout that. I'm observing the same behavior from your question.  I'm not noticing it for answers though - I'm looking into my own at the moment.

Comment: maybe I am looking at the wrong spot, but where does anything say "earlier this month"?

Comment: From the navigation menu, click on your username name. Then, in your recent activity section, if you posted a question in January 2014, you would see it under "earlier this month".

Comment: Since this isn't a SO related bug I migrated it over here. What's happening is our calculation is based off number of days, rather than actual month/year limits.